# How to pass multiple parameters to cron job with curl?

Tags: curl, cron

I'm running two cron jobs:

This one executes without a problem:

```
curl -sS http://example.com/cronjob.php?days=1
```

But this doesn't run at all:

```
curl -sS http://example.com/cronjob.php?days=1&month=1
```

Is this because of the ampersand (`&`)? If yes, how to pass multiple parameters?

Using `argv` is not an option.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You'll notice that this doesn't exactly work in your shell, either.

What you need to do is put single quotes around the URL, like so:

```
curl -sS 'http://example.com/cronjob.php?days=1&month=1'
```

Comment: Windows user running curl binaries should use double-quotes instead of single quotes to get multiple query parameters command working.

Comment: This works for me - many minutes wasted not understanding why my second parameter wasn't working.

Comment: Welp, I feel stupid now.  I was also forgetting my quotes.  Thanks man.

Answer (score 23):

As an alternative way, you can use \ before & which is a special character for shell. Generally, & is one of special characters that are meaningful for shell.

So, using a backslash [beside Quoting solution] can be a good solution to this problem. [more](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-the-bash/1565923472/ch01s09.html)

In your example you can simply apply this command:

```
curl -sS http://example.com/cronjob.php?days=1\&month=1
```

Comment: ➕1 for actually explaining the issue being `&` behaving as a special character [which as i looked it up on your link indicates 'background job' ]

Comment: this was the exact reason that my curl didn't work. thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Try a POST Request

```
curl -d "days=1&month=1" www.example.com/cronjob.php
```

Comment: Any particular reason you suggest a POST?

Comment: No harm in mentioning it, it's good to know (Although I'll go with GET)

Comment: well it just up you you also could do it with a GET request. This is just how i would do it. However this would work, and that is the point :-)

Comment: You can not know if it will work - it depends on the script if it looks POST variables or only GET variables.

Comment: on the receiving end it wont matter ($_REQUEST) but using an implicit string as URL not sure how post would work. Using GET or REQUEST will retrieve the variables