# Perl and curl - data missing when sending XML

Tags: xml, web-services, perl, curl

I'm calling a simple web service from a Perl program.
The web service just returns some simple XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<job>
    <path>/root/subdir1/subdir2</path>
</job>
```

When I call the web service on a browser I get the full XML returned and can 'see'

```
/root/subdir1/subdir2
```

When I call the same URL using curl from different linux boxes it loses the data. I get this back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<job>
    <path></path>
</job>
```

I don't understand why it is dropping the data but still returning the XML.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So you got a different response. Find out what's different about the request. Then address the difference.

Comment: Hi. The request is exactly the same. I have hardcoded the data in the response. So the response should always be the same.

Comment: So you've said: The request sent is the same, the response sent is the same, the response received is different. Something you've said isn't true. Find out what.

Comment: @Tenakha: There's much more to a request than a URL. Cookies, specific user agents, certificates and redirects are common barriers, but there's a lot of potential request headers the host might expect too.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this question. The reason why I was not getting the response was because when calling curl with more than one url param you need to surround the full url with quotes.

If you only have one query string param this will work:

```
curl -sS http://www.mywebsite.com/myprog.pl?myparam1=1
```

but this won't:

```
curl -sS http://www.mywebsite.com/myprog.pl?myparam1=1&myparam2=2
```

unless you do this:

```
curl -sS 'http://www.mywebsite.com/myprog.pl?myparam1=1&myparam2=2'
```

Found the answer here:

[How to pass multiple parameters to cron job with curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981923/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-cron-job-with-curl)

Thank you! :-)