# & in http get request

Tags: node.js, get

I try to write a server which will manage some get requests like this:
GET http://some-server.aa:1337/action?param1=1000&param2=1000
But I can't parse param1 and param2 from url because param2 not appear on server part.

```
app.get('/action', function(req, res) { 

  var parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var query = parts.query;
        console.log('keys: '+Object.keys(query)); //output: keys: caller
        console.log('url: '+parts.path); // output: url:/action?param1=1000

});
```

I use express, url, and path modules. if I'l be able to receive on server full url, then 

But before this, I need to be able to receive full path from req. Have any ideas?

**UPD**
how it's look from my side:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12720156/nodejsbug.png

Comment: You should be able to see all params in the query string. What does `console.log(req.query)` and `console.log(req.url)` show you?

Comment: console.log(req.query) -> [object Object]; console.log(req.url) -> /action?param1=1000

Comment: "[object Object]? Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.query))` then

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(req.query)) -> {"param1":"1000"}

Comment: I can't understand why it ignore all what come after "&" in request...

Comment: From what I can see, there is no param2... A stupid question, but are you 100% sure you're really sending a request with param2 set?

Comment: :) My request http get http://localhost:1337/action?param1=1000&param2=2000. Is my second day I'm trying to solve this problem...

Comment: How it's possible???? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12720156/nodejsbug.png

Comment: node log: GET /push?param1=1000 200 0ms - 17b

Comment: Where does that underlined line come from?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was not in node.js. It was in CURL request which I use. From browser it works fine.
Solution was found here: [How to pass multiple parameters to cron job with curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981923/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-cron-job-with-curl)

with request: curl -sS 'http://server.aa:1337/action?param1=1&param2=2' it works fine.